# Annoying popup that i don't know how to delete when using Ajax to execute php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

i'm going to try and do this question in a format that will make it easy for people to understand. :)

**Problem:**

People have been helping me with my coding, and one of these codes include a popup that says either error, or a success message. Every time i press the button that executes the php code, it executes the popup and i have to press close. The popup is white and has a close button that is blue in the bottom right corner. Every time i try to delete something to stop the popup, it either makes the code not work or shows an empty popup box.

**My Code:**

*php code being executed:*

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dummyUser";//dummy
$password = "dummyPassword";//dummy
$dbname = "DummyDatabaseName";//dummy
$skin = $_SESSION['active_skin'];

// Create connection

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

// You must enter the user's id here. /\

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch the existing value of the cash_amount against that particular user here. You can use the SELECT cash_amount from users where userid = $userid
$_SESSION['active_skin'] += 1;
$newAmount = $skin += 1;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET active_skin = $newAmount WHERE id = $userid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result)
{
   echo "skin color changed!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

*Javascript Ajax Code:*

```
function changeskin1white()
{

  $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
            data : { },
            url  : 'skin1.php',              // <=== CALL THE PHP FUNCTION HERE.
            success: function ( data ) {
                alert( data );               // <=== VALUE RETURNED FROM FUNCTION.
            },
            error: function ( xhr ) {
                alert( "error" );
            }
        });

document.getElementById('skin1').src="../images/skins/skin1red.png";
document.getElementById('skin1whitebtn').setAttribute("id", "skin1redbtn");
document.getElementById('skin1redbtn').setAttribute("class", "skin1redbtn");
document.getElementById('skin1redbtn').setAttribute("onclick", "changeskin1red()");

}
```

*Html Button that executes code:*

```
  <img src="../images/skins/skin1white.png" id="skin1"/>

  <p style="position: relative; top: 190px; font-size: 20px; left: -25px;">Circle &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tire &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Square &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Fan &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gear</p>

          <button  id="skin1whitebtn" class="skin1whitebtn" onclick="changeskin1white()" action="skin1.php"></button>
```

**Conclusion:**

I have no idea what is making this popup happen, even deleting the:

```
if($result)
{
   echo "skin color changed!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

didn't fix it, it just made an empty popup. Please be easy on me, i'm learning php, one step at a time :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alert()` function is most likely what's causing your problem.  It's a javascript command that opens a popup, displaying the contents passed to the function.  If you delete or comment out the following two lines, the popups should go away.

```
alert( data );
alert( "error" );
```

Comment: Nope, when i press the button nothing happens anymore :/ no popup, but no php being executed.

Comment: I took your advice and scanned my whole code, i commented out several things, and once i got the right combination, i succeeded. You guided me on the right path and i thank you for that. Have a green check, and a nice day. :)